# Change locator object appearance inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, locator

I have read earlier discussions of changing Locator appearance in Manipulate. I would like to change the rendered size of the locator object based on one of the manipulate variables. I can't get anything to work.

Here is an attempt.
source is an image, with dimensions {3716,3449}

```
isize = 240;
dim = ImageDimensions[source]
height = dim[[2]];
Manipulate[(
  locator = 
   Graphics[{Red, FaceForm[Opacity[.1]], 
     EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, Red]], Rectangle[]}, 
    ImageSize -> (isize size/height)];
  sub = ImageTake[source, height - (pt[[2]] - {0, size - 1}), 
    pt[[1]] + {0, size - 1}];
  Row[{Image[source, ImageSize -> isize], 
    Image[sub, ImageSize -> isize]}])
 , {{pt, {820, 1810}}, Locator, Appearance -> locator}
 , {{size, 100}, 10, 1000}]
```

Comment: Does the image needs to be that large? Can another image available online be used so we can all test the code coherently?

Comment: Here is a version using a smaller image pulled from the web.

Comment: source = ColorConvert[
   Import["http://vision.arc.nasa.gov/images/otto_shade_award3.jpg"], 
   "GrayScale"];
isize = 240;
{width, height} = ImageDimensions[source];
Manipulate[(
  locator = 
   Graphics[{Red, FaceForm[Opacity[.1]], 
     EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, Red]], Rectangle[]}, 
    ImageSize -> (isize size/height)];
  sub = ImageTake[source, height - (pt[[2]] - {0, size - 1}), 
    pt[[1]] + {0, size - 1}];
  Row[{Image[source, ImageSize -> isize], 
    Image[sub, ImageSize -> isize]}])
 , {{pt, {100, 100}}, Locator, Appearance -> locator}
 , {{size, 30}, 1, 30}]

Answer (score 8):

In this implementation, the function `locator[x]` takes the slider value as input. You can move the red box around as a locator and change its size with the slider.

```
source = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"]; 
locator[x_] := SetAlphaChannel[Image[Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[]}], ImageSize -> 10 x], 0.2];
Manipulate[Image[source, ImageSize -> 500], 
 {{pt, {100, 100}}, Locator, Appearance -> locator[size]}, {{size, 10}, 1, 30}]
```

[image]

The opacity is done by setting the alpha channel in an image created from the red rectangle rather than by using the opacity command in the Graphics command.